# How do I check installation directories in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am studying The Well Grounded Rubyist, in which I have an exercise to look at the installation directories and configuration of Ruby using the following options:

```
    irb --simple-prompt -rrbconfig 
    >> Config::CONFIG["binddir"]
```

- RbConfig is the library that has "a lot of precompiled information about the ruby installation"
- Config::CONFIG is a constant that identifies the hash table where Ruby has it's configuration settings.
  My trouble is that I get the error message "**Use RbConfig instead of the obsolete and deprecated Config**".

It seems to me that irb does not recognize Config::CONFIG as a constant.

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 8.

**How do I check the configuration data structure of Ruby?**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--simple-prompt`?

Comment: Yes. --simple-prompt. It was an error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config` is deprecated:

```
 $ irb
 001> Config
 (irb):1: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
 => RbConfig
```

You should do

```
 002> RbConfig::CONFIG
 => { ... humongous hash ... }
```